# Spring boot controller not returning the jsp page

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

**EDIT :** Below is the LatherupApplication Application class:

```
package latherup.com.latherup;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "latherup.com")
public class LatherupApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(LatherupApplication.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LatherupApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Below is my home controller :

```
package latherup.com.latherup;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String navigateToHomePage() {
        return "home.jsp";
    }
}
```

Below is the pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>latherup.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>latherup</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>latherup</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>13</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
        

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!--plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins-->
         <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Below is the home.jsp :

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <caption>Your todos are</caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Target Date</th>
                        <th>Is it Done?</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Todo 1</td>
                            <td>10/12/2017</td>
                            <td>No</td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-warning" href="/edit-todo">Edit Todo</a></td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-warning" href="/delete-todo">Delete Todo</a></td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="/add-todo">Add a Todo</a>
                
            </div>
            <script src="webjars/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The controller is returning String "home.jsp" instead of the page. I have added all the dependencies but not sure what is the problem. Is the problem with the versions of dependencies? If Yes, how can I decide on how to choose the versions that are compatible with each other. I keep facing this problem. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Please guide me on this as I am a beginner.

EDIT :
[Below is the image of project structure :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP2bh.png)

Application.properties :

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/LATHER-UP/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
```

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp`

So your controller should return `home` not `home.jsp`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String navigateToHomePage() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I suspect the problem is with the location of jsp file.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `RestController` for returning the JSP. Use `Controller` annotations for working on view part.

Read more about it here [Controllers](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controllers)

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun May 09 13:35:09 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template [home.jsp], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Comment: see this if you have correclty configured jsp in spring boot https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsp

Comment: Yes, all the configuration seems fine.

Comment: After adding version tag to pom.xml, now I get this error : Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun May 09 13:58:55 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: can you share your controller and application.properties/yml and project structure as well. That would help

Comment: I have added the application.properties and project structure. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I think you deploy in a web container, to do this you should use **SpringBootServletInitializer** in your main class,  This binds your application's Servlet, Filter, and ServletContextInitializer to the runtime server, which is necessary for our application to run:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.baeldung.boot.jsp")
public class SpringBootJspApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(SpringBootJspApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootJspApplication.class);
    }
}
```

**And you should not use @RestController in the controller for jsp view, It should be @Controller**, like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/book")
public class BookController {

    private final BookService bookService;

    public BookController(BookService bookService) {
        this.bookService = bookService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/viewBooks")
    public String viewBooks(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("books", bookService.getBooks());
        return "view-books";
    }
}
```

Please see this spring boot with jsp section [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsp)

Comment: I have updated it as per the link shared by you. But it still doesn't work for me. Please check the Code again.

Comment: I have seen your project structure, the main problem is the location of your JSP its not in this location : ${project.basedir}/main/webapp/WEB-INF/<jsp folder or jsp>

Comment: I am not understanding what is the problem with the location. I did change the folder name to WEB-INF but no luck

Comment: As what folder structure shared in this location https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP2bh.png by you, the home.JSP file is not in proper location what spring boot lokks, it should be in this location : latherup/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/LATHER-UP/home.jsp.(folder is not there please create webapp/WEB-INF)
And also change your controller don't return hom.jsp, just return home string like this:
 @GetMapping("/home")
    public String navigateToHomePage() {
        return "home";
    }

Answer (score -2):

try this out

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public ModelAndView navigateToHomePage() {
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("home.jsp");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

and while using this remove the suffix and prefix from application.properties

Comment: It is not working. 
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun May 09 13:27:11 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template [/home.jsp], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers